Using vba in ms access to combine column values
I have a table called contacts. That table has two columns i need to work with: company (company name) and location (county they are in).  Location may have multiple values or not, it's filled by county names that separated by "; " I need to be able to run through these table records and do the following:

find any of the entries that have matching company values
check to see if the location values for any matching company entries all match each other
if the location value differs, update the location values for that company to be an alphabetized and concatenated list of all distinct values found, separated by "; "

I've tried the below code (forgive me for any formatting errors), but what ends up happening is it repeats and fills a cell up to the max characters because if the location values aren't exactly the same, it just adds it to the end and sees its different when it hits again. After reflecting on this,  I understand where the logic is failing but I am not sure at this point if I'm on the right path here or if I should scrap this and try a completely different way of doing this. Any help/examples of what might work here would be appreciated.
Private Sub Command14_Click()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim holdcomp As String
Dim holdloc As String
Dim holddep

holdcomp = ""
holdloc = ""

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("Contacts")

rst.MoveFirst

Do Until rst.EOF

If holdcomp = "" Then
holdcomp = rst!Company
End If
If holdloc = "" Then
holdloc = rst!Location
End If
If holdcomp = "" Then
holdcomp = rst!Company
End If

If holdcomp = rst!Company And holdloc = rst!Location Then
rst.MoveNext
End If
  
If holdcomp = rst!Company Then
If Not holdloc = rst!Location Then
rst.Edit
rst!Location = holdloc & "; " & rst!Location
rst.Update
holdloc = rst!Location
rst.MoveFirst
End If
End If
rst.MoveNext
Loop

End Sub


disregard the "holddep" variable.  that's for the next step of this process which is to make sure only people in certain departments (another column of values seperated by "; ") get the updated value, but i feel once i have a handle on the first part that it shouldn't be too difficult to incorporate

Saving multiple data elements to a single field is poor design. Company/location pairs should be a related table where each company/location is a record. Accomplishing with current structure probably needs to use a collection or dictionary object.

Edit question to provide data sample as a formatted text table. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support

Query all of the distinct company names, and for each company query all of the county values - loop over that recordset and split the value on ; - collect the unique values and sort them alphabetically, then update the table with the new location list for each company.

Also, saving the locations associated with a company in every contact record that references same company is duplicating data and another violation of basic relational database principles of normalization. Compounding frustrations with multiple data elements in single field.

Ultimate solution is to normalize data, at least more than you have now. At a minimum, have a Companies table where each record is a unique company with a field to store associated locations. Probably a multi-value field would be better than a semi-colon delimited string. Save the CompanyID into Contacts table.

Consider this simple dataset:



ID
ContactName
CompanyName
Location




1
a
x
l;m;p


2
b
y
p;q


3
c
z
l;r


4
d
x
h;j;l



And procedure that will merge locations for each company without duplicates.
Sub LocationsCleanUp()
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rsCon As DAO.Recordset
Dim rsCom As DAO.Recordset
Dim colLoc As Collection
Dim aryLoc, x, strLoc
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rsCom = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT DISTINCT CompanyName FROM Contacts;")
Do While Not rsCom.EOF
    Set rsCon = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Contacts WHERE CompanyName='" & rsCom!CompanyName & "'")
    Set colLoc = New Collection
    Do While Not rsCon.EOF
        aryLoc = Split(rsCon!Location, ";")
        For Each x In aryLoc
            On Error Resume Next
            colLoc.Add x, x
        Next
        rsCon.MoveNext
    Loop
    
    'add code here to sort collection elements
    
    strLoc = ""
    For Each x In colLoc
        strLoc = strLoc & x & ";"
    Next
    'do something with the new string - maybe an UPDATE sql action such as
    'CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE Contacts SET Location = '" & Left(strLoc, Len(strLoc) - 1) & _
    '                  "' WHERE CompanyName='" & rsCom!CompanyName & "'"
    Debug.Print rsCom!CompanyName, Left(strLoc, Len(strLoc) - 1)
    rsCom.MoveNext
Loop
End Sub

On Error Resume Next may not be best practice but it was expedient. Alternatively, have code that checks if item is already in collection. Here is one example from https://analystcave.com/vba-collection/ (which also uses Resume Next). I have seen more complex versions and seems error trapping or looping collection are the options.
Function CollectionContains(myCol As Collection, checkVal As Variant) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    CollectionContains = False
    Dim it As Variant
    For Each it In myCol
        If it = checkVal Then
            CollectionContains = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function

For sorting procedures, review How do I sort a collection?

thank you for your help on this, it worked perfect to at least stop the duplication and gave me space to still learn some stuff on my end.  exactly what i needed!

Figured it might help someone else if I post my completed project here, only major changes made from the accepted answer were:

add the order by in the second select statement to get an alphabetized result

1st - 1 was changed to a - 2, which seems to have fixed an issue
where if there was no new data on the company it would add an extra
";" to the end of the location field every time i ran through
everything,

additional condition in the where portion of the update statement to filter out records matching an additional condition (based on a different columns value) from being affected by the update.  this was not part of the original question needing answered.
  Dim db As DAO.Database
  Dim rsCon As DAO.Recordset
  Dim rsCom As DAO.Recordset
  Dim rsDep As DAO.Recordset
  Dim colLoc As Collection
  Dim aryLoc, x, strLoc
  Set db = CurrentDb
  Set rsCom = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT DISTINCT Company FROM 
  Contacts;")

  Do While Not rsCom.EOF
  Set rsCon = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Contacts WHERE 
  Company='" & rsCom!Company & "' order by location")
  Set colLoc = New Collection
  Do While Not rsCon.EOF
  aryLoc = Split(rsCon!Location, "; ")
  For Each x In aryLoc
  On Error Resume Next
  colLoc.Add x, x
  Next
  rsCon.MoveNext
  Loop

  strLoc = ""
  For Each x In colLoc
  strLoc = strLoc & x & "; "
  Next


  CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE Contacts SET Location = '" & Left(strLoc, 
  Len(strLoc) - 2) _ & "' WHERE Department not like '*pre-design*' 
  and Company = '" & rsCom!Company & "'" 
  Debug.Print rsCom!Company, Left(strLoc, Len(strLoc) - 1)
  rsCom.MoveNext

  Loop



